drizzle-kit push:pg "serial" is not recognized
I have a backend project saved in a repo that uses Drizzle ORM, cloned on 2 PCs (Win and MacOS) that have the latest image of Posgtres. Pushing schema works only on MacOS, giving error on Win
> error: "serial" type does not exists
    at \node_modules\drizzle-kit\bin.cjs:24462:21
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async PgPostgres.query (\node_modules\drizzle-kit\bin.cjs:25423:21)
    at async Command.<anonymous> (\node_modules\drizzle-kit\bin.cjs:63261:9) {
  length: 89,
  severity: 'ERRORE',
  code: '42704',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
> schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'parse_type.c',
  line: '274',
  routine: 'typenameType' 

I have already tried to
delete and clone the repo
update node
reinstall postgres image
The behavior should be the same on both PCs

The serial type have some weird behaviors with Postgres DB, it
"The data types smallserial, serial and bigserial are not true types, but merely a notational convenience for creating unique identifier columns (similar to the AUTO_INCREMENT property supported by some other databases)."
Check for more info.
